# "Unresolved variable or type" for predefined objects

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

For some reason, from one day to the next (it may have been a day when my computer crashed), my IntelliJ became unable to resolve predefined JavaScript objects/classes/functions. All elements in the array below cause the warning `Unresolved variable or type <identifier>`.

```
var wtfIntelliJ = [window, Object, Function, Array, String, Number, Date, undefined, NaN];
```

I have all predefined libraries enabled, including "EcmaScript L5", with the project root as the scope.
Strangely, IntelliJ can still resolve the methods within these classes, so this doesn't cause any warning:

```
wtfIntelliJ.push("etc");
```

Going to the declaration of `push`, I got to a file called ECMAScript.js2 and it seems like all problematic identifiers have this warning:

> Object is located in file out of source root, certain functionality will not be available.

But I still don't know what this means and how to fix that, I certainly never touched this file.

Comment: please try invalidating caches (File/Invalidate caches, restart0 - does the problem persist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, [lena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274212/lena), that solved the problem.

> File -> Invalidate Caches...

After restarting and a couple of minutes "indexing", IntelliJ went back to normal.